# OracleSQLDeveloper Loop through all columns in all tables to find and document the table and field name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My company migrated to a new DB (from SQL Server to Oracle) and I was not provided much documentation on the new DB and how it mapped vs the old DB.  I need to find specific values in the new DB  and be able to determine what table/column they are found in.  I am looking for a query or a stored procedure to loop through the tables looking in each column and row for a specific value.  Once that value is found I need to document the name of the table and the field that the value is found in.  I'm not sure if this could best be accomplished with a query or a stored procedure or if there is another way to accomplish this.

-Charlie

Comment: How much data are we talking about? # tables #column #rows?  THat may drive the approach.  It may not be the fastest method, but take a look at DBMS_SQL package for dynamic sql.  You can obtain the column names/values programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; see if it helps. Read comments within the code.

As I'm using SQL*Plus for this example, I'm enabling output:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
```

Example one:

```
SQL> -- Looking for a string: SCOTT
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_str   varchar2(500);   -- SELECT statement to be used as dynamic SQL
  3    l_value varchar2(20);    -- value you are looking for
  4    l_cnt   number;          -- number of rows that contain L_VALUE value
  5  begin
  6    -- I'm looking for a string SCOTT in current schema
  7    l_value := 'SCOTT';
  8
  9    -- Loop through all tables; I'm restricting the list to only two tables.
 10    -- You'd probably want to remove the WHERE clause
 11    for cur_t in (select table_name
 12                  from user_tables
 13                  where table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
 14                 ) loop
 15      -- Loop through all columns in every table from CUR_T
 16      for cur_c in (select column_name
 17                    from user_tab_columns
 18                    where table_name = cur_t.table_name
 19                      -- Adjust data type, according to L_VALUE value because if
 20                      -- you're looking for a string, you can't just compare it to
 21                      -- e.g. DATE datatype; you'll get the "invalid number" error
 22                      and data_type like '%CHAR%'
 23                   ) loop
 24        -- Compose a SELECT statement. It might differ, depending on value you're
 25        -- looking for. Strings have to be enclosed into single quotes (CHR(39))
 26        l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_t.table_name ||
 27                 ' where '|| cur_c.column_name || ' = ' ||
 28                 chr(39) || l_value || chr(39);
 29
 30        -- To make sure it is correctly written, display it first using
 31        -- dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 32
 33        -- Run the SELECT statement
 34        execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 35
 36        if l_cnt > 0 then
 37           -- SCOTT was found in some table; display it
 38           dbms_output.put_line(cur_t.table_name ||'.'|| cur_c.column_name ||
 39                                ' contains ' || l_cnt || ' values I am looking for');
 40        end if;
 41      end loop;
 42    end loop;
 43  end;
 44  /
EMP.ENAME contains 1 values I am looking for

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Example two: lines I modified are #3, 7, 22 and 28 (searching for a number instead for a string):

```
SQL> -- Looking for number "10"
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_str   varchar2(500);   -- SELECT statement to be used as dynamic SQL
  3    l_value number;          -- value you are looking for
  4    l_cnt   number;          -- number of rows that contain L_VALUE value
  5  begin
  6    -- I'm looking for a number 10 in current schema
  7    l_value := 10;
  8
  9    -- Loop through all tables; I'm restricting the list to only two tables.
 10    -- You'd probably want to remove the WHERE clause
 11    for cur_t in (select table_name
 12                  from user_tables
 13                  where table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
 14                 ) loop
 15      -- Loop through all columns in every table from CUR_T
 16      for cur_c in (select column_name
 17                    from user_tab_columns
 18                    where table_name = cur_t.table_name
 19                      -- Adjust data type, according to L_VALUE value because if
 20                      -- you're looking for a string, you can't just compare it to
 21                      -- e.g. DATE datatype; you'll get the "invalid number" error
 22                      and data_type = 'NUMBER'
 23                   ) loop
 24        -- Compose a SELECT statement. It might differ, depending on value you're
 25        -- looking for. Strings have to be enclosed into single quotes (CHR(39))
 26        l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_t.table_name ||
 27                 ' where '|| cur_c.column_name || ' = ' ||
 28                 l_value;
 29
 30        -- To make sure it is correctly written, display it first using
 31        -- dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 32
 33        -- Run the SELECT statement
 34        execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 35
 36        if l_cnt > 0 then
 37           -- "10" was found in some table; display it
 38           dbms_output.put_line(cur_t.table_name ||'.'|| cur_c.column_name ||
 39                                ' contains ' || l_cnt || ' values I am looking for');
 40        end if;
 41      end loop;
 42    end loop;
 43  end;
 44  /
DEPT.DEPTNO contains 1 values I am looking for
EMP.DEPTNO contains 3 values I am looking for

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query on DBA_TABLES and DBA_TAB_COLUMNS to get all schemas tables.